# error: cannot convert value of type 'ObjCBool' to expected argument type 'Bool' on Swift 4.1.2 and Kitura on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu, kitura

I have a plain vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 and installed OpenSSH, Curl and Swift 4.1.2 on it.
The base example (swift package init --type executable) works but when I want to use Kitura framework I got a compile error if I 'swift build' it.

The error:

```
/.build/checkouts/Kitura.git--4845395383860597130/Sources/Kitura/staticFileServer/FileServer.swift:138:21: error: cannot convert value of type 'ObjCBool' to expected argument type 'Bool'
            if !isDirectoryBool {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

error: terminated(1): /home/thewall/swift-4.1.2-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /home/thewall/zSwift/.build/debug.yaml main output:

My package.swift file looks like:

> import PackageDescription
>
> let package = Package(
>      name: "zSwift",
>      dependencies: [
>     .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git", >.upToNextMinor(from: "2.1.0")),
>      ],
>      targets: [
>          .target(
>              name: "zSwift",
>              dependencies: ["Kitura"]),
>      ]
>   )

uname -a gives:

Linux thewall 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any ideas?

Comment: This should be probably reported to the Kitura issue tracker.

Comment: Do you want me to post it elsewhere?

Comment: Hmm, looking into the source code, are you still using Swift 4.0?

Comment: no, Using 4.1.2 downloaded yesterday

Comment: me too :-)   swift --version
Swift version 4.1.2 (swift-4.1.2-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kitura is handling it correctly, see https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/blob/master/Sources/Kitura/staticFileServer/FileServer.swift#L95

However, you are using an outdated Kitura version that has not been updated for your Swift version. Please, update Kitura to the latest version which is currently 2.4.1.